# jQuery - load POST response into iframe

Tags: jquery, servlets, post, iframe

I pose a problem that is making me lose my mind.
I need to develope a servlet for cobrowsing, whose logic is:
a "master" type an address in the addressbar, and a POST method (a form) sends this information to the servlet.

The servlet through the object HttpGet retrieves the requested resource and adds a tag  to solve any problems due to relative links.

the returned resource is then displayed in an IFRAME (the form of the search bar had as target the iframe)

When I click on any link on the page within the iframe the action of the link, with jquery, is prevented (event.prevent()) and in its place will be sent a POST that updates the page displayed in the iframe.

the update works and the servlet does its job properly, in fact the POST response contains the html of the page requested.

Now the problem: how do I display it in the iframe?

I tried with:

```
$('.myIframe').contents().load("myServlet", {someParameters});
```

and with:

```
$.post("myServlet", {someParameters}).success(function(data) {
$(".myIframe").contents().html(data);});
```

but in both cases i receive correct response (the html) but the iframe is empty.
Moreover, in these cases, the browser can not resolve relative links (with firebug the resource requirements referenced with relative links are not met, and receive a 404 response), although the first call (the addressbar) the  work.

Any idea?

P.S. sorry for my English!

the HTML code is:

```
<div id="searchbar">
<form action="myServlet" target="navigation" name="form" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="goTo" id="addressbar">
</form></div>
<div id="iframe"><iframe class="myIframe" scrolling="no" name="navigation"></iframe>
```

and, when iframe is loaded, each click on a link is recognized by:

```
$('.myIframe').load(function() {
   $('.myIframe').contents().find('a').click(function(event) {  
      $('html', $('.myIframe').contents()).load("myServlet", {someParameters});
   });
});
```

the type of data obtained in the post response is a typical web resources (the same you would get browsing outside the servlet cobrowsing - html, asp, php, etc.)

@Yevgeniy: Hi, it works, but now, when loading a page in this way, is not enabled the event of recognition of the click on a link (iframe load() event not fired?)

some updates
I separated the action of POST (which updates the session cobrowsing) by GET (instead asynchronously retrieves the resource session and should show iframe)

POST side is ok,

asynchronous GET is implemented using AsyncContext and this JS (oracle tutorial):

```
var messagesWaiting = false;          
function getMessages(){
    if(!messagesWaiting){
        messagesWaiting = true;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                messagesWaiting = false;
                var iframe = $(".browser")[0].contentWindow.document;
                iframe.open();
                iframe.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
                iframe.close();
            } 
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "CoBroServlet?t="+new Date()+"&type=UPDATE&sharedSessionId="+ document.getElementById("ssid").innerHTML, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
setInterval(getMessages, 1000);
```

the strange thing is that in some cases it works fine, but in other cases the entire contents of a GET containing the remote resource is printed "raw" on the screen (it is not put into #document nested in iframe but between )

to explain better:
Sometimes (always to the first search in addressbar) firebug shows that the content of the iframe is the expected one.
Browsing the site through iframe interaction with the servlet and outputs are ok.

Suddenly (doing a new search in addressbar) the iframe prints the contents of the GET response.

From this time also repeating the search in addressbar of the first site (the one that worked well) is printed to the screen the raw html of the page.

I also tried to clear the iframe every new cycle of getMessages function () with $ ('. MyIframe). Empty (), but I do not get anything different!

Comment: Post more info like your html, what type of data is being returned, ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing parameters encoded as path of the request, simply going to replace the src attribute of the iframe:

```
$(".myIframe").attr('src', "myServlet/"+encodedParam);
```

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

please modify your javascript like this and try again:

```
$('html', $('.myIframe').contents()).load("myServlet", {someParameters});
```